# Как запретить доступ к диску с Windows 10 на Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

Есть 2 ноутбука, на каждом стоит Windows 10 и Ubuntu 20.04 отдельной системой на другом разделе диска.

На первом ноутбуке:
В Ubuntu в файловом менеджере я вижу раздел с Windows 10, но не имею к нему доступа (при попытке туда зайти получаю ошибку "Unable to access location" "No .Filesystem or .Encrypted interface on D-Bus object". При этом я ничего не делал специально для закрытия доступа, так было изначально после установки.

На втором ноутбуке:
В Ubuntu в файловом менеджере также вижу раздел с Windows 10, но могу зайти в него и имею доступ ко всем файлам Windows.

Обе системы ставил схожим образом (на Windows разделял диск; при установке Ubuntu выбирал "Установить Ubuntu рядом с Windows", разделы создавались автоматически).

**Вопрос:** как на втором ноутбуке запретить доступ к диску с Windows аналогично, как на первом? Чтобы вообще никак нельзя было получить доступ туда, даже с правами администратора.

P.S. Если это поможет, можно даже переустановить Ubuntu и что-то поменять на этапе установки.

P.P.S. Из Windows я не вижу раздел с Ubuntu (и это хорошо).

P.P.P.S. Идеально будет, если обе системы будут изолированы друг от друга, и Ubuntu вообще не будет видеть диск с Windows.

Comment: `Encrypted` — ну, зашифруйте фс и на второй машине. и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Что именно и чем зашифровать? Это можно сделать прямо из Ubuntu?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/security/information-protection/encrypted-hard-drive

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, но, к сожалению, для не админа описанный выше способ слишком сложный и непонятный + есть риск, не имея никакого опыта в данном деле, навредить как системе, так и диску. Я думал, может есть какое-то более изящное и простое, а главное безопасное, решение.

Comment: ну вы же как-то на одном ноутбуке это сделали. вот и сделайте **точно так же** и на втором.

Comment: Из описания вопроса: "При этом я ничего не делал специально для закрытия доступа, так было изначально после установки.". То есть я понятия не имею, почему на первом ноутбуке он был зашифрован.

Comment: значит, во время установки это было сделано. вот и повторите точно такую же процедуру установки и на втором ноутбуке.

Comment: Там нет никаких специальных опций для выбора, зашифровать ли диск или нет. На первом ноуте я ставил Убунту давно, но ничего такого не делал при установке. Это может быть из-за разных версий Windows (на первом ноуте она была намного старее, когда я ставил Убунту), или из-за разных версий биоса, или из-за разных дисков?

Comment: я веду речь о файловых системах ms/windows. соответственно, говорю и про установку ms/windows.

Comment: Хм, вообще первый ноут был уже с Виндой, а на втором я ее ставил сам. Возможно, следует попробовать ее переустановить и глянуть, есть ли что-то подобное на этапе установки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось зашифровать диск с Windows. Порядок действий, которые я совершил:

1. Запустить шифрование диска из Windows при помощи BitLocker (клик правой кнопкой мыши на нужный диск)
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   Тут у меня возникла ошибка "Это устройство не может использовать доверенный платформенный модуль (TPM)".
   Решить ее помогла эта статья https://remontka.pro/bitlocker-without-tpm-windows/.
   После этого смог начать шифрование. Выбрал вариант с паролем, ключ восстановления записал на флешку, выбрал "шифровать весь диск"
2. Далее потребовалось перезагрузить компьютер и ввести заданный ранее пароль. После того, как комп загрузился, начался процесс шифрования.
3. Дождаться окончания процесса шифрования - и все! Дальше можно пользоваться системой как обычно (пароль от Битлокера не нужно вводить каждый раз при входе в систему). И теперь из Ubuntu я не могу зайти в Windows (при попытке получаю ту же самую ошибку "Unable to access location", как я указал в описании вопроса).